# Angular4 How to load a module in an eager way

Tags: angular

In Angular4, you can lazy load your module using the `loadChildren` attribute in your routing config with `pathToMyModule#MyModule`. I was wondering if there was any attribute I could specify to always load my module (so basically disabling the lazy loading).

Comment: read this article [Avoiding common confusions with modules in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/avoiding-common-confusions-with-modules-in-angular-ada070e6891f)

Answer (score 4):

import all the modules in the module that you bootstrap when you start the application. In general it is called `AppModule`. It is the default way though. Then don't use `loadChrildren`. The modules should import each other **hierarchically**, then all modules will be imported eagerly.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
       AppRoutingModule,
       LoginModule,
       //here you should import all other modules, or other the modules should import each other hierarchically
    ],
    declarations: [
       AppComponent      
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent] 
})

export class AppModule { 

}

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot([
         {path: '', component: SomeComponent}     
   ],
   exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}




@NgModule({
    imports: [
        LoginRoutingModule
    ]
})
export class LoginModule {
}


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: 'login',
        children: [
          {path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'somepath'},
          {path: 'somepath', component: SomeOtherComponent}, 
        ]
      }

    ])
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class LoginRoutingModule {
}
```

Comment: So there is no other way then ending up with a single route file ?

Comment: @Scipion I have editted the answer